# Android - Launch other app module from one app module

Tags: android, android-studio, module, android-library, multi-module

We have an application X and we want to create an application Y with the same functionality as this application but with a different package name.

In addition, we need to be able to open a pull request to the Y application through the improvements we have made in the X application. However, when the package name is changed in the Y application, conflicts arise because the imports change.

We also want to run X application module from Y application module with different package name by splitting it into two separate application modules.

However, I cannot start XActivity of X application from YActivity in Y application module.

I hope I was able to explain my purpose and problem. Can anyone show me the way?